# How can I improve RSA d-key generation in c++?

Tags: c++, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm writing a c++ implementation of RSA algorithm. It work but It takes hours to calcultate d key. Any help to make it work faster would be awesome.

```
unsigned __int64 calcolo_d(const unsigned __int64 eulero, const unsigned __int64 e)   {

register unsigned __int64 d = 0;

while (!((e*d) % eulero == 1))
{
    ++d;
}

return d;   }
```

Comment: Aside `register` is obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are computing is the modular inverse of `e` mod `eulero`. This can be done efficiently via the [extended euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Modular_integers).

There are many, many implementations out there to choose from.